# Swap name in same same column in oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

In a table there is data.like this one

```
ID      NAME
1   Apple
2   Apple
3   Apple
4   orange
5   orange
6   orange
7   Apple
8   Apple
9   Apple
10  orange
11  orange
12  orange
```

data may be more then 1000 times. now there is need to swap/change/update apple to orange and orange to apple.

Comment: Why did you tag this with MySQL **and** Oracle?

Answer (score 7):

You would do this with a `case` in an `update` statement:

```
update t
    set name = (case when name = 'Apple' then 'Orange'
                     when name = 'Orange' then 'Apple'
                end)
    where name in ('Apple', 'Orange');
```

This is standard SQL and will work in both MySQL and Oracle.

If you don't need to actually change the name, but just to swap it in a `select`, then do the logic in the query:

```
select (case when name = 'Apple' then 'Orange'
             when name = 'Orange' then 'Apple'
             else name
        end) as name
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update  YourTable
set     name = 
        case name
        when 'Apple' then 'Orange'
        when 'Orange' then 'Apple'
        end 
 where  name in ('Apple', 'Orange')
```